# Accessing edge attributes from a tuple in GraphX

Tags: apache-spark, graph

I have another problem with my graph. My edges contain three attributes as a tuple, so an edge looks like

> (verticeId_1, verticeId_2, (Attr1, Attr2, Attr3)).

I am trying to create a subgraph containing only edges where `Attr2>100` (Attr2 is a number). So I try this:

```
val gr2=graph.subgraph(epred=(id1: String, id2: String, attr: Tuple) => attr(2)>100)
```

but become the error *Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters*. Is there some workaround for this issue?
Thanks in advance.

The edges are defined as

```
val ed = df.rdd.map(x => ((MurmurHash.stringHash(x(3).toString), MurmurHash.stringHash(x(4).toString)), (x(0),x(1),x(2)))).map(x => Edge(x._1._1, x._1._2,x._2))
```

from the dataframe `df` which contains attributes as columns 0, 1, 2 and vertices as columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgraph function can take vertex and edge predicates.  For the edge predicate it requires a function that takes an EdgeTriplet object and outputs a boolean.  The EdgeTriple object has attributes that will give you access to info about both vertices and that attributes of the link that you created.  To implement your case, try this:

```
g2 = graph.subgraph( epred=(triplet) => triplet.attr._3 > 100)
```

Here is the documentation for EdgeTriple that shows you what attributes you have available to you:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeTriplet

Also, note that your edge attributes are a tuple, so they must accessed using members like "_1", "_2", etc instead of array indexing using parenthesis.

**EDIT:** For reference, here is the a full self-contained example:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

val data = Seq(
    (10, 11, 12, 1, 2),
    (10, 11, 13, 1, 3),
    (10, 11, 14, 1, 4),
    (10, 11, 15, 2, 3),
    (10, 11, 16, 2, 4)
)

val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF


val ed = df.rdd.
            map(x =>((MurmurHash3.stringHash(x.getString(3)), MurmurHash3.stringHash(x.getString(4))), (x.getInt(0), x.getInt(1), x.getInt(2)))).
            map(x => Edge(x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))

val graph = Graph.fromEdges(ed, 0)

graph.subgraph( epred=(triplet) => triplet.attr._3 > 5)
```

Comment: Thank You! Unfortunately it doesn't work also, I have the error message *<console>:46: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeTriplet[String,(Any, Any, Any)]*

Comment: Now I have *<console>:46: error: value > is not a member of Any* I suppose that I had to define the edges somehow in a different way. :(

Comment: I added the full example code I was using to test.  That shows how I defined the edges.  Is that the same way you were doing it?

Comment: Not quite, I have to define them from a dataframe, how I done it is described above in the original question.

Comment: So I use MurmurHash to convert vertices into strings and I suppose I need some similar function to convert the attributes also, so they are not of type "any" any more.

Comment: The issue with your graph building is when you access the Row object used in DF rows with array indexing it returns an Any type.  There are specific methods for retrieving the right type. Updated again.